# Will having different names in my passport versus academic diploma be a problem when applying for a Schengen tourist visa?

Tags: schengen, passports, paperwork, tourist-visas

There's a surname written in my passport, but none in my academic diploma. Will this be a problem while applying for a Schengen tourist visa? Which documents should i submit for my tourist visa?

Comment: Info needed: Is it common for your country to omit surnames in diplomas? If so, the people handling visa applications are likely familiar with that.

Answer (score 4):

The country where you applying for Schengen visa should provide you all the tourist visa application requirements and check list. You could gathered all information either from embassy/ consulate or through  VFS (visa facilitation service) at your home country. As far as my previous experience with Schengen countries, there is no degree requirement for tourist visas. Therefore surname in degree not a matter.

Answer (score 3):

For a tourist visa, you have to establish that you plan to *go back* after the visit. Your degree matters only to show that you have a stable and well-paying job at home. If the bank statement and the employment contract look good, the degree should be no problem.